# Limitations of Standalone Script as Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-libraries

I'm creating a standalone script so users can use it as Library in their Spreadsheets' bound script.

As you know to use a standalone script as a Library, you have to set "Share" to "Anyone with the link" - at least - as viewer and "Save new version" of it.

My questions are:

1. How many users can use Classes/Methods included in my shared standalone script (Library) at the same time (concurrent users)?
2. If my shared standalone script (Library) includes Classes/Methods `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties` | `UrlFetchApp.fetch` | `ScriptApp.newTrigger`, how quotas and limitations are measured? Is it against each User or against the Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library runs under the authority and uses the quota of the account that added your project (the "library") to the project that they own.  The number of accounts that have added *your* library to *their* Apps Script project is immaterial to the usage quota in *your* account.  If that's what you were wondering.  If the account that added your library has multiple users, and they had lots of concurrent users, then it could affect their account, but not yours.  That is also the same with an add-on.
You can see the quotas at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

If you had an Apps Script Web App published to run as YOU, and was available to anyone, then that situation would affect *your* account quota.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I need!